# Mac OS X Lion git push

Tags: macos, git, osx-lion, libiconv

On Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2 when i try to push to remote repository using ssh

I get

```
ld.so.1: git-receive-pack: fatal: libiconv.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

libiconv.2.dylib files are found both in
    /usr/local
    /usr/local/lib

I've tried recompiling latest git 1.7.7.3 and libconv-1.14 from sources with

```
./configure --with-iconv=/usr/local
```

But it didn't fixed the problem

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a problem on your remote? git-recieve-pack is used to recieve, what is pushed into a repo, see [git-recieve-pack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-receive-pack)

Comment: You mean that git-receive-pack is executed on remote host? I'll check it now

Comment: Yeah thx, that was it, post an answer and i'll close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that this is not a problem on your remote? git-recieve-pack is used to recieve, what is pushed into a repo, see [git-recieve-pack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-receive-pack)